# java8 time package to execute code block based on GMT time zone

Tags: java, time, java-8

We have requirement belongs to java.time, I think i can fullfill this using this package but not getting the right approach; here is the scenario

our application is running on the server, we dont know the local timezone of server.
But we have to run our application code block(while loop) from 2:00am to 6:00am GMT on daily how can I achive it, Thanks in advance.

```
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.now();
System.out.println("Localtime: "+localTime);
LocalTime localTimeGMT = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("GMT"));
```

Answer (score 4):

To check if the current GMT time of day is between 2 AM and 6 AM, do this:

```
int hour = LocalTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).getHour();
if (hour >= 2 && hour < 6)
    System.out.println("It is now between 2 AM and 6 AM GMT");
```

Comment: Thanks, What is the importance of ZoneOffset here?

Comment: @user1272269 None. `ZoneOffset.UTC` is just a built-in constant for UTC, instead of using named lookup to find GMT, since (in computers) GMT and UTC is the same. Note that `ZoneOffset` *is* a `ZoneId`.

Comment: If I want to execute it b/w 2am to midnight 11:59 pm then how can I do?

Comment: @user1272269 Are you asking how to *start* running your code at a certain time? That is a broad question. E.g. is you Java program running 24/7? If not, then you need an OS scheduler, e.g. CRON on Linux and Task Scheduler on Windows.

Comment: Yes, I know I decided not to use cron expression with my retry mechanism in sprint boot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52241119/spring-task-scheduling-spring-retry-issue-while-running-application so plannin go for this alternative approach. Thanks so please suggest how can I achive to run b/w 2:am to 11:59 pm time

Comment: @user1272269 Please think about it: On an 24-hour clock, "2 AM to midnight" is simply `hour >= 2`.

Answer (score 3):

You can Use ZonedDateTime and specify timeZone. You can fetch the hour from ZonedDateTime.

```
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("GMT")));

            int hour = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("GMT")).getHour();
            if(hour>=2 && hour<6)
            {
                //some logic 
            }
```

Comment: Correction in your answer is to find the hour; int hour = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("GMT")).getHour();

Comment: Can you please explain? you want to run some code between 2am to 6am right ?

Comment: thanks to edit your answer, Yes between 2am to 6am based on GMT time zone, how can i do the same if 2am to 11:59pm based on gmt?

Comment: ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("GMT")) this will give you time in GMT.11.59PM will 23.59.

Comment: `hour>2 && hour<6` means that it'll run between `3 AM` and `6 AM`.

Comment: Yes, Andreas, this is just condition. user will update it as per need:) Thanks for pointing out

Comment: `ZonedDateTime` is a bit overkill for UTC. I’d prefer `OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).getHour()`.